# Is there a way to have a generic type as a list in a class?

Tags: java, generics

Basically, I have this class.

```java
public class DoubleValues<A, B> {
}
```

I can do whatever I want with it, but my limitation is the amount of generic types specified: 2.

Is there a way to do something like this, to allow many generic types to be specified?

```java
public class InfiniteValues<V...> {
}
```

This would allow me to do something like this:

```java
new InfiniteValues<A, B, C, D>();
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: No. Would be useful for MethodHandles through.

Comment: But how would you ever use them? You can't define an unlimited number of fields `A a, B b, C c ...`

Comment: If this has something to do with a functional interface where you can have n arguments, then you can always use currying or something, although that's not very nice in Java

Comment: Forgot about `FunctionInterface`s.

Comment: @user, was just wondering if it was possible.  I have one practical use for it but it works fine with the DoubleValues class shown before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for could be described as *varargs typing*.

Java does not support this.